# MySQL russian text error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with inserting proper data into my DB with php...
I am trying insert some data with this code:

```
$query1 = "insert into `exercises`(`exercise_name`) values ('".$txtEName."');";
        $query2 = "insert into `exercises_type`(`type_name`) values ('".$txtEType."');";

        mysqli_query($connnect, $query1);   
        mysqli_query($connnect, $query2);
```

all data is russian text... all data is saving into the DB, but, in DB it looks like [image: this]

so what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the charset/collation of the columns?

Comment: @Explosion Pills it is - utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score -1):

You can check for correct charset/collation. As this may help you to insert correct data in you table. also you can use character encoding for values your are getting by $_POST.

This [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html) may help you